# Como usar getElementsByClassName em um objeto Internet Explorer no VB.Net?

Tags: vb.net, microsoft-access, internet-explorer, macro

Estou tentando utilizar um getElementsByClassName em uma macro do Access.
Está apresentando erro na linha:

```
If ie.Document.GetElementsByClassName("msgErroAdic").Length > 1 Then
```

Sendo `Dim ie as Object` e `Set ie = CreateObject("InternetExplorer.Application")`
Retorna o erro que não é possível localizar o método.
Encontrei esse site: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms535862%28v=vs.85%29.aspx#methods
Nele não existe o método GetElementsByClassName no objeto InternetExplorer. 
No entanto, nesse outro site: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh773165%28v=vs.85%29.aspx existe o método GetElementsByClassName.

Gostaria de saber qual a diferença.

Vi também outras questões onde indicam criar uma função, mas também não funcionou. `Public Function GetElementsByClassName(Source As HtmlDocument, ClassName As String) As HtmlElement()` Erro de compilação: "O tipo definido pelo usuário não foi definido".

Comment: Experimente definir `ie` como `variant` e depois criar o objeto com `CreateObject("InternetExplorer.Application")`. Veja se ajuda e avisa.

Comment: Sim, esqueci essa parte, já está assim.

Comment: @PedroMVM eu tentei definir como `Variant`, mas não funcionou também.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Menu Referências]

No menu Referências, deve ativar:

- Microsoft Internet Controls
- Microsoft HTML Object Library

O código abaixo foi a base para resolver o problema.
O segredo é que a propriedade `GetElementsByClassName` é apenas de elementos HTML, então foi necessário definir o objeto como `HTMLDocument` antes de usar `GetElementsByClassName`

```
Public Sub navegar()

Dim ie As SHDocVw.InternetExplorer
Dim html As HTMLDocument
Dim elementos As Object
Dim item As Object

Set ie = New InternetExplorer
ie.Visible = False

ie.Navigate "https://pt.stackoverflow.com/"

Do While ie.ReadyState <> READYSTATE_COMPLETE
    DoEvents
Loop

Set html = ie.Document
Set elementos = html.getElementsByClassName("horizontal-manchete")

For Each item In elementos
    Debug.Print Trim(item.innerText) & vbCrLf
Next

MsgBox "Fim"

ie.Quit
Set ie = Nothing

End Sub
```

Espero ter ajudado.